# Reading url image from plist string

Tags: iphone, xcode, plist, cell, tableview

I have a plist with dictionary.
In the dictionary i have a string called "cellPic" that have url address of an image.
I'm trying to populate my table view with images that i put on my dropbox account & read them through the plist string.
("arrayFromPlist" is my array)
The problem is that when i run it, i'm getting an error in the console:
[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector

This is my code:

```
-(void) readPlistFromDocs
{
    // Path to the plist (in the Docs)
    NSString *rootPath =
[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
    NSLog(@"plistPath = %@",plistPath);
    // Build the array from the plist  
    NSMutableArray *arrayFromDocs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
if (arrayFromDocs)
{
    NSLog(@"\n content of plist file from the documents \n");
    NSLog(@"Array from Docs count = : %d", [arrayFromDocs count]);
}
    arrayFromPlist = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayFromDocs];
}   

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

// Returns the number of rows in a given section.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrayFromPlist count];
    NSLog(@"Array SIZE = %d",[arrayFromPlist count]);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[arrayFromPlist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"cellPic"]];
NSData *urlData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:urlData]];

return cell;
}
```

My other question is - how can i load the images asynchronous when i read the url from the plist string?
I tried to find an example for that but i found only asynchronous without uisng plist.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change Following line

```
NSDictionary *arrayFromDocs = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

[Best Tutorial for load the images asynchronous](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2010/05/downloading-images-for-table-without.html)

Hope, this will help you..